# Nav menu Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, nav, elementor

I have wordpress and Elementor Pro.  When I add a Nav menu it looks good on the preview but when I publish the page there appear to be no CCS or javascript styling.  Any ideas?

Thank you

Richard

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, but i had to re-install Wordpress and Elementor Pro.  Not really a solution and i hope it does not happen again